# ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'raspi-gpio_git'. I am using 'rpi-hwup-image.bb' image in which i added a bbappend file to install raspi-gpio_git

Tags: yocto, gpio, bitbake, openembedded, meta-raspberrypi

From meta-raspberrypi I am using the rpi-hwup-image.bb recipe to build the image in which I have appended raspi-gpio_git recipe, but i am reciving the following error:

```
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'raspi-gpio_git' (but /home/lala/yocto/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-core/images/rpi-hwup-image.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'raspi-gpio_git' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['raspi-gpio_git']
ERROR: Required build target 'rpi-hwup-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['rpi-hwup-image', 'raspi-gpio_git']
```

I have the following in my bblayers.conf :

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/lala/yocto/meta-raspberrypi \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/lala/yocto/poky/meta-qt5 \
  "
```

How do i resolve this error?

I am still at early learning stages and any feedback and help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_git is the version, just use raspi-gpio.

Comment: Thanks that worked, could you explain why this worked and the previous did not ?,  does the reference manual cover all this? I haven't gone through it in detail, just skim thorough it whenever i want to know something.